# Is there a way to tell the browser not to prompt the user to remember the password on a specific page?

Tags: html, browser

In the registration page on the website I'm working on Firefox prompts the user if they want to save their password.

If the user chooses yes then the password is saved for the registration page which is quite useless considering that the login page is different, and that the browser will prompt the user *again* in the login page, which makes poor user experience.

Is there any way I can tell the browser that there is no need to save the password on the registration page?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following form tag ->

`<form id="<someid>" action="<action>" method="<method>" autocomplete="off">`

Not sure that all browsers support it -> https://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution right after posting the question:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

disables prompting the user to remember the password, and turns off auto complete of fields which is a good idea for a registration form.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the name and/or id/class of the password input something else than password, passwd, pass. I believe FF tries to recognize password fields by looking at their names.